# Any tips for reading sequencer piano roll notation?

Tags: notation

I'd like some hints reading piano roll notation in Cubase LE. At the moment when I see the vertical piano keyboard on the left-hand side of the window I'm sort of turning my head, imagining it horizontal.

Seems that everything that's on a stave can be represented in piano roll, e.g. note pitch, duration, bends, articulation and so on. I'm comfortable with using visual cues in stave notation, so for instance if a three note chord has notes on three adjacent lines (or three adjacent spaces) I know it's probably a root position triad. Or I can see if two notes are a third or a fifth or an octave apart. And so on.

What should I be concentrating on when I'm reading (or writing) piano roll? Are there corresponding visual cues that I can use to speed up my reading. It's really slow at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely slow. Personally I find the horizontal staff line of notation a closer visual metaphor than the vertical piano keys. The only problem is that accidentals all get their own line, making it hard to eyeball intervals...

Comment: Wait, the Cubase piano roll notation displays dynamics? (I find this to be a traditional display weakness in piano roll and MIDI notation such as Synthesia.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci You can see note velocities via a vertical bar graph below the piano roll.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Logic displays velocity in piano roll with color coding of the notes. Cool colors are low velocity, warmer colors are higher. Kelly green is approx 64.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox She's 73 [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Green_(musician)], but a gentleman wouldn't mention it.

Comment: The thing this question made me think of is how the traditional keyboard layout reflects the layout of the stave: they both contain the principle of the diatonic scale, that is to say they are organised on a diatonic rather than chromatic basis; whereas the piano roll accords equal space to all 12 tones. There's no reason really why one should be better/worse than the other, but perhaps the diatonic organisation was more /useful/ at certain points historically, I don't really know. I might attempt a proper answer to the question asked later.

Comment: Piano roll doesn't impart the harmonic context - for instance it can tell you to play the left-hand black note in a group of three black notes. But it doesn't tell you whether to think of that black note as an F# or a Gb. Stave notation would tell you.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - Famitracker renders all black notes as sharps, so at some level (and with 12TET being ubiquitous in these parts), accidental notation doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @JudyN. "perhaps the diatonic organisation was more /useful/ at certain points historically": it was certainly more useful in the middle ages before the chromatic scale had been invented.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I find helpful it to think in terms of interval classes. This allows me to focus on the guide lines rather than the absolute pitches, thus largely ignoring the piano keyboard.

I found it fairly quick to train myself to see intervals in terms of the number of grid lines lay between pitches. So a major chord would look, vertically, like <0,4,3>, and a minor chord would be <0,3,4>. It takes a little while to get used to thinking of chords this way, but one starts to see "stacks of thirds", even when inverted, in a manner analogous to the way one learns to see them on a keyboard.

Octaves are especially easy to see, since each note will be equidistant from the "C" markers above and/or below. And seconds (1s and 2s) are also an easy starting place.

In general, I found harmonic intervals to be the best starting place. Once I began to see them more easily, my feel for melodic intervals followed.